# While setting NSString to NSURL, NSURL is returning nil value

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

I have to parse the return of a JSON API for which I've taken the URL into a string and after that I passed it NSURL but in NSLog it is showing nil.
Here is my code,

```
NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.v3.factual.com/t/places?q=%@&geo={\"$circle\":{\"$center\":[19.9909631,73.8034808],\"$meters\":40000}}&limit=20&KEY=123456",[self.strurl lowercaseString]];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlstring ];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must encode your url as it contains special characters, Try something like this

```
NSString *paramString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/t/places?q=%@&geo={\"$circle\":{\"$center\":[19.9909631,73.8034808],\"$meters\":40000}}&limit=20&KEY=123456",[self.strurl lowercaseString]];

NSString *encodedSearchString = [paramString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.v3.factual.com%@", encodedSearchString];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSLog(@"urlstring is %@",url)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If this has helped you, please mark it as your correct answer. Thanks

Comment: can you please xplain how you did that??

Comment: sorry I didn't get it, what do you want me to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Tested and Working

```
-(void) sample
{
   // NSString *strurl = @"hello";
    NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.v3.factual.com/t/places?q=%@&geo={\"$circle\":{\"$center\":[19.9909631,73.8034808],\"$meters\":40000}}&limit=20&KEY=123456",[strurl lowercaseString]];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%@",req);
}
```

Comment: @pankaj jha! Is the API KEY = 123456 which you are using in the url is it a valid key obtained from factual.com! because JSON Viewer is giving the following error!! The API key provided is invalid. To request an API key, please visit http://www.factual.com/devtools/beta."